# How to import an tmx map in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, tiles, pytmx

I have made a *tmx map in the Tiled Editor program. Then I tried to import it into my game. When I change the variable `layers` to `0` it works, but there is only 1 tile on the screen. I want to print the entire map on my screen. But I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pytmx\pytmx.py", line 512, in get_tile_image
    layer = self.layers[layer]
IndexError: list index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LL\Desktop\Erik\RPG_project\RPG project\data\main.py", line 143, in <module>
    game_initialize()
  File "C:\Users\LL\Desktop\Erik\RPG_project\RPG project\data\main.py", line 117, in game_initialize
    map_setup()
  File "C:\Users\LL\Desktop\Erik\RPG_project\RPG project\data\main.py", line 140, in map_setup
    image = tmxdata.get_tile_image(0, 0, 2)
  File "C:\Users\LL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pytmx\pytmx.py", line 514, in get_tile_image
    raise ValueError
ValueError
```

I think it has to do with my layers. I have only 1 layer for my map. Still my script doesnt work. I also use Base64 (compressed) for my map. And 32 pixels large tiles.

```
from pytmx import load_pygame

def map_setup():
    global image

    # Getting / Importing the map
    tmxdata = load_pygame("Tile_files\\mymap2.tmx")

    image = tmxdata.get_tile_image(0, 0, 1) # x, y, layer
```

Comment: Is there more than one layer in your map file? The TMX function `get_tile_image()` returns a single tile image, so getting a single image from the 0th layer describes what is written in the question - thus this matches what one would expect to happen.

Comment: @Kingsley I have 1 layer i n my map file. Im trying to get all layers on the screen. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because tile seems only (0,0) position. You have to gave loops the layers. I wrote this code maybe help you.

```
from pytmx import load_pygame, TiledTileLayer

def map_setup():
    global image

    # Getting / Importing the map
    tmxdata = load_pygame("Tile_files\\mymap2.tmx")
    width = tmxdata.width * tmxdata.tilewidth
    height = tmxdata.height * tmxdata.tileheight

    ti = tmxdata.get_tile_image_by_gid
    for layer in tmxdata.visible_layers:
        if isinstance(layer, TiledTileLayer):
            for x, y, gid, in layer:
                tile = ti(gid)
                if tile:
                    image = tmxdata.get_tile_image(x, y, layer)
```

By the way, excuse me for my language. Hopefully works.

Edit: You can look this video detailed for import tmx map in pygame. Video link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QIXyj3WeyZM

Comment: This code iterates through the tiles in the layers.  Typically the user wants to draw each tile image to a surface during this loop, e.g.: `surface.blit( tile, ( x * tmxdata.tilewidth, y * tmxdata.tileheight ) )` where `surface` is a `pygame.Surface` the size of the map section to render.

Comment: Hey! Sorry for late reply. But thanks for the video link tho your code did not really work with my script. I still have a hard time understanding tiles.

Answer (score 2):

I think @gurbuz's answer covered most of this already, so I will present much the same answer, but with my own spin ;)

So your TMX map defines a grid of textured-tiles which make up a screen full of map/level/whatever.  Just like ceramic floor tiles, they are each handled individually, and placed on the floor individually.

The code in the question looks correct to find the (0,0 / upper-left) *single* tile in layer zero of the map and draw it to the screen.  I suspect it's producing an error for `layer=1` because the map only contains one layer.  But without the map, it's impossible to know.

To show the entire map, it's necessary to loop over every tile defined in the `.tmx` file, and place them onto a surface.  This surface can then be simply `.blit`~ted to the pygame window.

I cobbled together this basic function which loads the entire map, rendering it to a surface.  This is a naïve way to do it, because this image could be *huge*.  But it serves the purpose of illustrating how to traverse the elements of the map and draw them.

```
# Convert HTML-like colour hex-code to integer triple tuple
# E.g.: "#892da0" -> ( 137, 45, 160 )
def hexToColour( hash_colour ):
    red   = int( hash_colour[1:3], 16 )
    green = int( hash_colour[3:5], 16 )
    blue  = int( hash_colour[5:7], 16 )
    return ( red, green, blue )

# Given a loaded pytmx map, create a single image which holds a 
# rendered version of the whole map.
def renderWholeTMXMapToSurface( tmx_map ):
    width  = tmx_map.tilewidth  * tmx_map.width
    height = tmx_map.tileheight * tmx_map.height

    # This surface could be huge
    surface = pygame.Surface( ( width, height ) )

    # Some maps define a base-colour, if so, fill the background with it
    if ( tmx_map.background_color ):
        colour = tmx_map.background_color
        if ( type( colour ) == str and colour[0].startswith( '#' ) ):
            colour = hexToColour( colour )
            surface.fill( colour )
        else:
            print( "ERROR: Background-colour of [" + str( colour ) + "] not handled" )

    # For every layer defined in the map
    for layer in tmx_map.visible_layers:
        # if the Layer is a grid of tiles
        if ( isinstance( layer, pytmx.TiledTileLayer ) ):
            for x, y, gid in layer:
                tile_bitmap = tmx_map.get_tile_image_by_gid(gid)
                if ( tile_bitmap ):
                    surface.blit( tile_bitmap, ( x * tmx_map.tilewidth, y * tmx_map.tileheight ) )
        # if the Layer is a big(?) image
        elif ( isinstance( layer, pytmx.TiledImageLayer ) ):
            image = get_tile_image_by_gid( layer.gid )
            if ( image ):
                surface.blit( image, ( 0, 0 ) )
        # Layer is a tiled group (woah!)
        elif ( isinstance( layer, pytmx.TiledObjectGroup ) ):
            print( "ERROR: Object Group not handled" )

    return surface
```

So once the map is "converted" to a surface, it's possible to simply blit this surface onto the pygame screen:

```
# Before the main loop starts
tmx_map   = pytmx.load_pygame( "test.tmx", pixelalpha=True )
map_image = renderWholeTMXMapToSurface( tmx_map )

# Main loop
while not finished:
    ...
    pygame_screen.blit( map_image, ( 0, 0 ) )
    ...
```

A better way of doing this would be to only load the elements of the TMX map necessary for display.  It's easy to record which sub-co-ordinates of the map are displayed, and then go generate - say the right-side column when this needs to come into view.